# Change view width with autolayout and size class enabled

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, autolayout

I have done sample screen for iPhone5s with autolayout and size class enabled in swift.I have a view at top of the screen which has 320(width).How do i automatically increase width of view for iPhone6 and iPhone6Plus screen.any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the width of your view to be the same as the width of iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus screens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the dimensions of your view to follow the same width as the one of the iPhone it's running on, in Interface Builder, position the view, size it so that it basically looks as you want it to look, and then add the constraints, ctrl drag from your view to it's superview and add "Leading space to container margin" and "Trailing space to container margin" constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set the width. You make constraints to the left and right edges of the superview so it will always be the width of the screen (assuming that the superview is the controller's self.view).